# How to read video file and save frame (image) using python built-in library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I want to read a video file and extract a random frame and save as image file. For this I tried the below code.

```
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
success, image = vidcap.read()
snapshot_path = f"{snapshot_name}.jpg"
cv2.imwrite(snapshot_path, image)  # save frame as JPEG file
```

The above code work properly but I have used opencv-python. I have to use my application into docker. So, I want to reduce docker size. In my entire application, I used cv2 for only the above function. If any built-in python library or light-weight python library is replaced for the above functionality it would be great improvement for reducing docker size.

Any other way I can try this?
Any hint would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless its a raw video, you will anyway need a video codec to decode the video. You can try **imageio** and **imageio-ffmpeg** package combination. Or you can try python wrapper for ffmpeg, **ffmpeg-python**.

https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/README.md#convert-video-to-numpy-array

https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html